# Geofence understanding Geofence lifetime

Tags: android, google-play-services, android-geofence, location-client

I've built Geofence as:

```
    GeofenceModel modelExit = new GeofenceModel.Builder("id_oi_456")
                .setTransition(Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_DWELL)
                .setExpiration(Geofence.NEVER_EXPIRE)
                .setLatitude(40.414341)
                .setLongitude(49.928548)
                .setRadius(CLIENT_GEOFENCE_RADIUS)
                .build();


    SmartLocation.with(this).geofencing()
                .add(modelExit)
                .start(this);
```

When set to NEVER_EXPIRE, it gets triggered. When setExpiration() is not set geofence will not be triggered though. The question is that What isdefault expiration time for single geofence?

Answer (score 0):

In regards to Android's `Geofence` class: it is not possible to create a `Geofence` using `Geofence.Builder` without setting an expiration. If you try to, it will throw `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Expiration not set.`

As for your `GeofenceModel` class, I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using com.google.android.gms.location.Geofence
underneath your GeofenceModel class.

You have an instance variable named `modelExit` indicates that you're waiting for the exit transition. while in your geofence configuration you're only listening to `GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_DWELL`. You should set the transition to `GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_EXIT`.